# Weird Noise in Blender Cycles Hair

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I've rendered a character's hair in Blender Cycles and I'm getting a strange result. It looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5171857/ezgif-2308112385.gif
I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Are my samples not high enough? (I'm currently using 49 samples.) I don't really think that the samples are what's causing it to do this because I thought that grain caused by low samples was static, not moving. This problem only occurs when my mesh is moving or the camera is moving, by the way.

What should I do to resolve this issue? If the samples are the problem, what would be a good sample number to ensure that this issue doesn't occur?

Comment: I've found that it's not actually the samples, but it's the hair literally jumping all over the place. Any ideas of how to fix this?